# SharePoint 2013 disaster recovery re-create database permissions

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

Imagine a on-premises SP2013 environment where everything is working fine until someone decides to install non-controlled software on the SQL server. That, somehow, causes losing ALL the permissions to the databases (including SharePoint DDBB).

You can access the SQL instance and remote desktop but no access to any DB whatsoever. neither with sp_install, sp_farm, or other system accounts related to SP. You don't have access at all.

My first instinct would be restoring a backup of those databases and pray (a lot for the permissions to be restored with it). Or adding manually but that's prone to errors, a pain in the.. And not a best practice at all...

Second instinct tells me to look for a magic powershell or try the SharePoint config Wizard (and in this case pray X 5)

Any insight for me from another fellow comrade that survived that situation?

Comment: What error u are getting when remote in? Access denied or can't see the Db? Can you make sure db are on sql? How many database you have?

Answer (score 1):

In this situation, I would do the following.

- Login SQL Server via SSMS with the Account which has full control of SQL( Server Admin/Security Admin)
- Make Sure SPfarm and SPinstall Account permission should be DB creator and Security Admin( if not fix that)
- Now Make both IDs as DBO on all sharepoint Config and Content and Service Db.
- Finally Give the App Pools Account DBO on Dbs.
- If you have multiple SQL server attach to the Sharepoint then repeat this on all SQL servers.
- Test it, if working fine otherwise. you may have to recycle Timer Service, IIS reset and Clear Config Cache.

Comment: Thanks a lot Waqas! Looks reasonable, I am waiting for the sys admins to desist trying to fix it :D when that happens I will give a try to these steps

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is make sure that the accounts are added to the Logins at the SQL Server level (not database level, that's unnecessary). All SharePoint service accounts will have appropriate permissions on the databases already -- that part is replicated (or restored with your database backups).